# Suppressing Widget.Wrapper without suppressing Widget.ControlWrapper

Tags: orchardcms

I have an alternate view for a widget. In that view I'm suppressing the wrapper using code like this:

```
Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Clear();
```

This works, but I'd like to only suppress the Widget.Wrapper. Right now it is also suppressing the Widget.ControlWrapper which prevents the edit buttons from displaying when I have the Widget Control Wrapper module enabled.

Is there any way to clear only the Widget.Wrapper while keeping the Widget.ControlWrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this for a similar problem, I was able to suppress the Widget.Wrapper thusly in a Widget-Sidebar.cshtml file in my theme:

```
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors;
@using Orchard.Environment.Extensions;
@{
    Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Remove("Widget_Wrapper");
    Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Add("Widget_SideBarWrapper");
    Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Add("Widget_ControlWrapper");
}
@Display(Model.Content)
```

I started out by using the Shape Tracing tool to create an alternate for widgets I had in a "sidebar" column (basically a `<div id="sidebar">` I have in my layout as `@Zone(Model.Sidebar)`).

I placed the code above in the Widget-Sidebar.cshtml alternate that I created using Shape Tracing.

```
Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Clear(); as used by the OP completely removes everything, to the point where in Shape Tracing it won't even show up as a widget. Adding my own alternate (Widget.SideBarWrapper.cshtml, which is added as "Widget_SideBarWrapper" above) would not fix this. I felt that was wrong even though the content displayed.

Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Remove("Widget_Wrapper");
```

seemed the right way to go (i.e., Shape Tracing still showed a Widget), but it appears to REMOVE all the other wrappers, so you then have to add your new wrapper along with Widget.ControlWrapper.cshtml (written as "Widget_ControlWrapper" in code above).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add back the Widget.ControlWrapper like this:

```
Model.Metadata.Wrappers.Add("Widget_ControlWrapper");
```

This seems to be working just like I wanted.