# Orchard CMS 100% unthemed html page

Tags: orchardcms

We have a requirement to use the content zone of Orchard CMS to enter in html for a full screen landing page. We managed to get an unthemed page type using the Downplay.Orchard.Layout selector. The problem is that in using the content zone orchard automatically wraps html, head and body tags around it. We want to remove this content so we essentially have a blank page to start off with and then we can create our own html to display on the landing page. Is this possible to do for a single page and if so what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a [URL alternate](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) or you can use the new Disable Template part (1.8, i think)
I have done lots of URL alternates in the past. Pretty easy.

Just remembered, a question like this: [Using Alternatives for Document.cshtml in Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877821/using-alternatives-for-document-cshtml-in-orchard-cms)

removing the Wrapper (Document.cshtml) from your (Layout-url-...) and adding a new one, should do the trick.

And it might be better to use the placement.info, but thats my opinion... 
[Suppressing Wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367453/suppressing-widget-wrapper-without-suppressing-widget-controlwrapper) and [Placement.info](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I will try the suggestions and then post back.